# Optimization defeats robustness measures

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am currently investigating robust methods for the summation of arrays, and implemented the algorithm published by Shewchuk in ["Adaptive Precision Floating-Point Arithmetic and Fast Robust Geometric Predicates"](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/robustr.pdf). While the implemented algorithm works as expected in `gfortran`, `ifort` optimizes the countermeasures away.

To give some context, here is my code:

```
module test_mod
contains
  function shewchukSum( array ) result(res)
    implicit none
    real,intent(in) :: array(:)
    real            :: res
    integer         :: xIdx, yIdx, i, nPartials
    real            :: partials(100), hi, lo, x, y

    nPartials = 0
    do xIdx=1,size(array)
      i = 0
      x = array(xIdx)

      ! Calculate the partial sums
      do yIdx=1,nPartials
        y = partials(yIdx)
        hi = x + y
        if ( abs(x) < abs(y) ) then
          lo = x - (hi - y)
        else
          lo = y - (hi - x)
        endif
        x = hi

        ! If a round-off error occured, store it. Exact comparison intended
        if ( lo == 0. ) cycle
        i = i + 1 ; partials(i) = lo
      enddo ! yIdx
      nPartials = i + 1 ; partials( nPartials ) = x
    enddo ! xIdx

    res = sum( partials(:nPartials) )
  end function
end module
```

And the calling test program is

```
program test
  use test_mod
  implicit none
  print *,        sum([1.e0, 1.e16, 1.e0, -1.e16])
  print *,shewchukSum([1.e0, 1.e16, 1.e0, -1.e16])
end program
```

Compilation using `gfortran` with produces the correct results for all optimization levels:

```
./a.out 
   0.00000000    
   2.00000000
```

`ifort`, however, produces zeros for all optimizations above `-O0`:

```
./a.out 
   0.00000000
   0.00000000
```

I tried to debug the code and went down to the assembly level and figured out that `ifort` is optimizing away the calculation of `lo` and the operations after `if ( lo == 0. ) cycle` .

Is there a possibility to force `ifort` to perform the complete operation for all levels of optimization? This addition is a critical part of the calculations, and I want it to run as fast as possible. 
For comparison, `gfortran` at `-O2` executes this code approximately eight to ten times faster than `ifort` at `-O0` (measured for arrays of length >100k).

Comment: Which, if any, other compilation options are you using with ifort?

Comment: @francescalus For this test, no other options. For debugging `-warn all -check`, for inspecting the assembly code `-S -fcode-asm -fsource-asm`.

Comment: There are probably some from site-wide, so could you look at the output from `-dryrun`, and in particular whether you have `-assume noprotect_parens`?  [If I use `-assume protect_parens` I get your expected answer - but there could be other things going on also.]  Although, that's a default, so may not be listed.

Comment: @francescalus I get dozens of options, but `-assume protect_parens` is not among them. I scanned through the options (too long to post here), but I cannot see anything suspicious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to floating point operations, the default for ifort is generally for performance rather than strict correctness.

There are a number of options to control the floating point behaviour.  Using ifort 16 and the option `-assume protect_parens` I get the expected behaviour even at higher optimization levels.

Additionally, there are the options `-fp-model precise -fp-model source` (this latter implies `-assume protect_parens`) which may also be of interest to you.  The default for `-fp-model` is `fast=1` which

> allows value-unsafe optimizations

Naturally, these may have an impact on performance, so other options around the floating point behaviour are also worth considering.

Much further detail can be found in an [Intel publication](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/pdf/fp-consistency-121918.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves my issue. Just as a side node, for this application, `ifort` (15.0.0) is slower than `gfortran` (5.2.0) by more than a factor of two on my machine (Taking the fastest run for each, and trying out various optimization options for both).

Comment: Do you know whether this can be specified as a compiler directive rather than a compiler option?

Comment: How did you construct your test cases?  I may have a quick play myself later on as this sounds interesting.

Comment: No idea about directives, I'm afraid, but I see they could be good, if you mean to just apply this correct calculation at the one point.  That linked document suggests some `#pragma`s for C/C++ and an ifort compiler directive for FMA, but not for the others.  So I guess not - but there's hopefully an expert about who can comment (here or at the Intel site).

Comment: I allocate a large array, fill it with `random_number`s, and perform the sum. The time is taken with `omp_get_wtime()` (because I'm lazy ;-)), taking care to exclude allocating and filling the arrays. Dummy rounds are included for warm-up.