# Is it necessary to append _kind to number literals in modern Fortran?

Tags: fortran, standards, gfortran

This might be stupid question but I'm a bit confused after some recent tests. I always thought the way Fortran deals with reals is the following (modern declaration):

```
program testReal

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: rkind=8

  real(kind=rkind) :: a,b,c

  // Test 1
  a = 1
  b = 1.
  c = 1._rkind
  write(*,"(2(1xES23.15))") a, b, c

  // Test 2
  a = 1/2
  b = 1/2.
  c = 1./2.
  write(*,"(2(1xES23.15))") a, b, c

  // Test 3
  a = 3.3
  b = 1 * a
  c = 1. * a
  write(*,"(2(1xES23.15))") a, b, c

end program testReal
```

Apart from `Test 2 - a` everything evaulates the same. I always thought I have to put e.g. `1._rkind, 0.5_rkind, etc.` after every real in order to make sure to fill the rest of the mantissa with zeros?

Is this just pure luck or is it really not neccessary anymore to attach the `_rkind`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look first at Test 1.  Here `1`, `1.` and `1._rkind` are literal constants.  `1` is an integer of default kind; `1.` is a real of default kind; `1._rkind` is a real of kind `rkind` (which could be the same kind as the default).  These are all different things.

However, in this case what happens on the assignment is key.  As `a`, `b` and `c` are all reals of kind `rkind` the corresponding right-hand sides are all converted to a real of kind `rkind` (assuming such a kind has greater precision than default kind).  The conversion is equivalent to

```
a = REAL(1, rkind)
b = REAL(1., rkind)
c = 1._rkind
```

It just so happens that `1` and `1.` are both, in your numeric model, convertable exactly to `1._rkind`.

I won't touch on Test 2, as the differences are "obvious".

In Test 3, we have the literal constant `3.3` which is a real of default kind.  Again

```
a = REAL(3.3, rkind)
b = REAL(1, rkind)*REAL(3.3, rkind)
c = REAL(1., rkind)*REAL(3.3, rkind)
```

due to where and how conversions happen.  From this you can see that the results are reasonably the same and the arithmetic happens as real of kind `rkind`.

What you will notice is a difference

```
a = 3.3
b = 3.3_rkind
```

because the (mathematical) real number 3.3 is not exactly representable in your numeric model.  And the approximations will differ with real of default kind and kind `rkind`.

In particular, there is no need to worry about "fill[ing] the rest of the mantissa with zeros".

Comment: So if I understand right if I do ‘a = 3.3 * c’ is different from ‘b = 3.3_rkind * c’ if c is of type ‘rkind’ and ‘rkind != default’ type? This is because the literal constant ‘3.3’ will always be of default type and as Vladimir stated before ‘3.3 != 3.3_rkind’.

Comment: Yes.  Crucially, the conversion to real of a different kind happens _after_ the interpretation of the literal default real constant.  You're potentially losing precision compared with `3.3_rkind`.  Numbers which are representable exactly at the two precisions will be identical in effect.

Comment: Perhaps see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34639858/3157076) for more detail on that.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped indeed!

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary to specify the kind for numbers which are exactly representable. All integer numbers that are not too big are exactly representable as an IEEE standard floating point number. Therefore it is not necessary for constants like `1.` or `3.`. Also one half is exactly representable in binary so `1./2.` will work fine.

It is necessary for other values, which are not exactly representable, becaause without the suffix the literal is treated as default kind (single precision). In your case `3.3` is NOT exactly representable and you will get different results

```
write(*,*) 3.3, 3.3_rkind

3.29999995       3.2999999999999998
```

Comment: So for which values would it be necessary? Something like ‘0.3’?

Comment: I added it, you read the answer too early, I was in the process of writing it.

Comment: Thanks! Can I give both of you reputation for answering my question? ;)

Comment: Don't care about reputation. Just mark one ínswer as accepted. And when after you becone sble to upvote, don't think about reputation. I think francescalus' answer contains nore details.