# Floating point consistency in a for loop

Tags: floating-point, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a question regarding consistency of floating point operations, but most resources I find online seem focused on consistency between different runs or different builds, not within the *same* run.

I have a big Fortran program that contains a large loop, in which the following floating point operation is repeatedly evaluated:

`y = (p*q*x+ q*q/2)/(sqrt(p*p+0.25_dp*q*q+p*q*x)*q)`

Here `p,q,x` are double precision floats obtained from arrays which are unchanged through the entire loop. The variable `x` can vary between -1 and 1, and both `p` and `q` are always positive. Hence mathematically the value of `abs(y)` should never exceed 1.

What I find is that sometimes a rounding error occurs that gives a value of y larger than `1` beyond double precision. This is not a problem of course, but it seems to occur at "random" iterations of the loop, even though the input values should be the same. Furthermore, I have found it very difficult to reproduce these errors in simpler code.

From these observations I would guess that there is some compiler optimization going on that affects the floating point accuracy. **My question is whether it is possible that such optimizations lead to inconsistent results even within the same run of the program, and the same loop?** Knowing this would give me some peace of mind that there is not something else wrong in the code.

I am using the Intel Fortran classic compiler, without any floating point specific options turned on.

Comment: Intel compiler default floating point behaviour is to [get the wrong answer quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254531/3157076). You should experiment with options if you care about correctness more than you care about quickness.

Comment: @francescalus: The question is not about correctness *per se*. If compiler optimization might cause a single `y = (p*q*x+ q*q/2)/(sqrt(p*p+q*q+p*q*x)*q)` to be evaluated **differently** in different iterations of a loop, then OP needs a method to avoid that, which then might involve “correctness” in the sense of controlling how floating-point expressions are evaluated. If compiler optimization does not cause this, then the symptoms point to some other bug in their program, such as corrupting array values. Thus, the crux of the post is how compiler optimization behaves in a particular regard.

Comment: In general, it is conceivable one instance of `y = expression` in source code may be evaluated differently in different iterations of the loop: If the compiler engages in loop unrolling and then optimizes the resulting code, one instance of `y = expression` might be evaluated using a fused multiply-add here or there, while the other is evaluated in some different manner. But it is hard to say. You should work to isolate specific values for which this occurs and then populate the arrays with entirely those values and then test whether the errors occur in a certain pattern of iterations.

Comment: Another approach is to compile to assembly and examine the instructions that evaluate the expression.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Exactly, I am wondering whether this behavior is just a result of compiler optimization or possibly some deeper issue with the code. I will try compiling to assembly and seeing what I can find.

Comment: You do know that you can cancel a factor of q out of the top and bottom of that fraction?

Comment: You can also rewrite that function to make it impossible for y to exceed 1.

Comment: While this most likely won't solve your actual question, you can rewrite the calculation of y as `y = (2 * p * x + q) / sqrt(4 * p * (p + q * x) + q * q)` , saving a few floating point operations including divisions.

Comment: @lastchance Yes I know, this is an old code I am refactoring, I don't know why it was originally programmed this way. I will likely rewrite this line in the future, but for now I was just interested in the origin of the floating point behavior.

Comment: As p, q, x are “obtained from arrays”, are you absolutely sure that this code has no bug involving accessing outside array bounds? That can lead to all sorts of mystical behaviour. It would be useful to see a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I have extensively checked the code both with compiler bounds checking and with valgrind, and never found any issue. Also the results of this code have always been in line with expectations. I am still trying to get a minimum working example, the problem is very tricky to catch.

Comment: I should also note that this problem seems to appear only when the code is compiled on AMD hardware. And that the loop in question is parallelized with openMP. Perhaps this leads to more aggressive compiler optimizations?

Comment: If anything is done in parallel, whether openMP or MPI, it is very difficult to get exactly the same double precision result every time. Since you can't guarantee the order that different processes will finish then reduction operations like summation may end up producing (slightly) different answers simply because things were added up in a different order. Just turn the openMP parallelisation off - even just for that loop - and see what happens. But if you can rewrite that function to avoid round-off problems (and you can, here) then I would do so.

Comment: For an example of what can happen just adding things up in a different order (as may happen on parallelisation) then try simply ```double precision :: A = 1.0, B = -1.0, C = 1.0e-20;   print *, A + B + C, A + C + B```

Comment: Yes, this is also something I considered, however the computation occurs in the innermost part of the loop and thus I assumed its evaluation would not be parallelized